# Fastest way to find text in folder

Tags: full-text-search, awk, grep, solaris

I was using the return value of `fgrep -s 'text' /folder/*.txt` to find if *'text'* is in **any** *.txt* file in */folder/*.  It works, but I find it too slow for what I need, like if it searches for *'text'* in all the files before giving me an answer.

I need something that quickly gives me a yes/no answer when it finds at least one file with the 'text'.  Probably some awk script.

Comment: A "no" answer is always going to be slow using this method because it will still have to search all the files. If you want something faster you have to index the files somehow.

Comment: Your question might be a tiny bit ambiguous or I might be over-thinking it. Your `fgrep` command is searching for occurrences of the string 'text' in all .txt the files in /folder/, but your *question* says "to find if there is any .txt file in /folder/". If the former then **mopoke's** answer should help although it's still going to search *each* file. If the latter, then you should use `find` - see my answer for details.

Comment: just edited to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to shorten your search if it's the kind that would be based on **mopoke's** answer. This stops after the first match in the **first file** in which it's found:

```
# found=$(false)
found=1    # false
text="text"
for file in /folder/*.txt
do
    if fgrep -m1 "$text" "$file" > /dev/null
    then
        found=$?
        # echo "$text found in $file"
        break
    fi
done
# if [[ ! $found ]]
# then
#    echo "$text not found"
# fi
echo $found # or use exit $found
```

**Edit**: commented out some lines and made a couple of other changes.

If there is a large number of files, then the `for` could fail and you should use a `while` loop with a `find` piped into it.

If all you want to do is find out whether there is *any* .txt file in a folder regardless of the file's contents, then use something like this all by itself:

```
find /folder -name "*.txt"
```

Comment: I would like to try your's, without de `-m1`, but I need it to return 1 if there is a match and 0 if not.  Not as an echo printout, but as a command's return value.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for asking, but scripting language is this?  I'm guessing Bash.

Comment: Yes, it's Bash, but something similar could be done with other shells. What shell do you use? Normally, 0 is true and 1 is false. Try this in Bash: `true; echo $?; false; echo $?` - you should get a zero then a one. See my edit above to show how to make use of this.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you want:

```
fgrep -m1
```

Which stops after one match.

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't work. Illegal option. I'm using it on a Solaris machine.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answers above, this should do it I think ?

```
find /folder -name \*.txt -exec grep "text" {}\;
```

But I'm not sure I fully understand the problem : is 'fgrep' doing a full depth recursion before it starts outputting or something ? The find should report as-it-finds so might be better for what you need, dunno.

[edit, not tested]: Change the 'grep' above for a shell-script that does something like:

```
grep "text" && exit 0 || exit 1
```

To get the true|false thing you need to work (you'll need to play around with this , haven't tested exactly the steps here - no access to Unix at the moment :-( )